# Tensorflow Sequence to sequence model using the seq2seq API ( ver 1.1 and above)

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

I'm using **TensorFlow v:1.1**, and I would like to implement a **sequence to sequence** model using tf.contrib.seq2seq api.
However I have hard time understanding how to use all the functions (BasicDecoder, Dynamic_decode, Helper, Training Helper ...) provided to build my model. 
 
Here is my setup: I would like to "translate" a sequence of feature vector: **(batch_size, encoder_max_seq_len, feature_dim)** into a sequence of a different length **(batch_size, decoder_max_len, 1)**.

I already have the **encoder** that is an RNN with LSTM cell, and I get its **final state** that I would like to feed to the decoder as initial input.
I already have the cell for my decoder, MultiRNNCell LSM.
Could you help me building the last part using the functions of **tf.contrib.seq2seq2** and dynamic_decode (an *example code* or *explanations* would be much appreciated) ?

Here is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.contrib import seq2seq
from tensorflow.contrib import rnn
import math

from data import gen_sum_2b2

class Seq2SeqModel:
def __init__(self,
             in_size,
             out_size,
             embed_size,
             n_symbols,
             cell_type,
             n_units,
             n_layers):
    self.in_size = in_size
    self.out_size = out_size
    self.embed_size = embed_size
    self.n_symbols = n_symbols
    self.cell_type = cell_type
    self.n_units = n_units
    self.n_layers = n_layers

    self.build_graph()

def build_graph(self):
    self.init_placeholders()
    self.init_cells()
    self.encoder()
    self.decoder_train()
    self.loss()
    self.training()

def init_placeholders(self):
    with tf.name_scope('Placeholders'):
        self.encoder_inputs = tf.placeholder(shape=(None, None, self.in_size), 
                                             dtype=tf.float32, name='encoder_inputs')
        self.decoder_targets = tf.placeholder(shape=(None, None),
                                              dtype=tf.int32, name='decoder_targets')
        self.seqs_len = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32)
        self.batch_size = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, name='dynamic_batch_size')
        self.max_len = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, name='dynamic_seq_len')
        decoder_inputs = tf.reshape(self.decoder_targets, shape=(self.batch_size,
                                    self.max_len, self.out_size))
        self.decoder_inputs = tf.cast(decoder_inputs, tf.float32)
        self.eos_step = tf.ones([self.batch_size, 1], dtype=tf.float32, name='EOS')
        self.pad_step = tf.zeros([self.batch_size, 1], dtype=tf.float32, name='PAD')

def RNNCell(self):
    c = self.cell_type(self.n_units, reuse=None)
    c = rnn.MultiRNNCell([self.cell_type(self.n_units) for i in range(self.n_layers)])
    return c

def init_cells(self):
    with tf.variable_scope('RNN_enc_cell'):
        self.encoder_cell = self.RNNCell()  
    with tf.variable_scope('RNN_dec_cell'):
        self.decoder_cell = rnn.OutputProjectionWrapper(self.RNNCell(), self.n_symbols)

def encoder(self):
    with tf.variable_scope('Encoder'):
        self.init_state = self.encoder_cell.zero_state(self.batch_size, tf.float32) 
        _, self.encoder_final_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(self.encoder_cell, self.encoder_inputs,
                                                        initial_state=self.init_state)
```

Comment: Have you gone through the [seq2seq tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/seq2seq)? It has an end-to-end example of encoding and decoding.

Comment: Hi, Have you figure it out?

Comment: @AllenLavoie I think the problem is that the API changed for v1.1 but the example has not been updated?

Comment: @NedRuggeri did you run into a specific error, or are there just new ops that haven't been included in that tutorial yet? If the former, a Github issue would be in order so we can track fixing it.

Comment: @AllenLavoie I don't think the tutorial code gives any errors: it just uses legacy functions which have been replaced by newer classes. If you're new it's pretty hard to figure out, but maybe I can make some suggestions when I understand it all :-)

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! If you can come up with a list of ops you'd like to see included, please do open a feature request on Github for updated seq2seq/RNN documentation.

Comment: Thanks guys I finally find out how to use the new seq2seq library

Comment: @AllenLavoie In the legacy seq2seq, there's embedding_attention_seq2seq which is not using bidirectional encoder. Can u point me to something which can help me in implementing that. 
I am looking for embedding bidirectional attention seq2seq.

Comment: @bot28: I'd recommend a new question. Mostly because I don't have a good answer for you (and someone else might), but also because the margin of this comment is too small to contain said nonexistent answer.

Comment: @AllenLavoie Sure. I will just write a new question.

Comment: @JimZer What sources did you use to understand how the new seq2seq API works? Thank you

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Decoding layer:**

The decoding consists of two parts because of their differences during `training` and `inference`:

> The decoder input at a particular time-step always comes from the output
>   of the previous time-step.  But during training, the output is ***fixed***
>   to the actual target (the actual target is fed back as input)  and this has shown to improve performance.

Both these are handled using methods from `tf.contrib.seq2seq`.

1. The main function for the `decoder` is: `seq2seq.dynamic decoder()` which performs dynamic decoding:

   `tf.contrib.seq2seq.dynamic_decode(decoder,maximum_iterations)`

   This takes a `Decoder` instance and `maximum_iterations=maximum seq length` as inputs.

   1.1 The `Decoder` instance is  from:

   `seq2seq.BasicDecoder(cell, helper, initial_state,output_layer)`

   The inputs are:  `cell` (an RNNCell instance),  `helper` (helper instance), `initial_state` (initial state of the decoder which should be the output state of the encoder) and `output_layer` (an optional dense layer as outputs to makes predictions)

   1.2  An RNNCell instance can be a `rnn.MultiRNNCell()`.

   1.3  The `helper` instance is the one that differs in `training` and `inference`. During `training`, we want the inputs to be fed to the decoder, while during `inference`, we want the output of the decoder in `time-step (t)` to be passed as the input to the decoder in `time step (t+1)`.

   **For training:** we use the helper function:
                   `seq2seq.TrainingHelper(inputs, sequence_length)`, which just read inputs.

   **For inference:** we call the helper function:
                   `seq2seq.GreedyEmbeddingHelper() or seqseq.SampleEmbeddingHelper()`, which differs whether it to use `argmax() or sampling(from a distribution)` of the outputs and passes the result through an embedding layer to get the next input.

**Putting together: the Seq2Seq model**

1. Get the encoder state from the `encoder layer` and passed it as a `initial_state` to the decoder.
2. Get the outputs of `decoder train` and `decoder inference` using `seq2seq.dynamic_decoder()`. When your calling both the methods make sure the weights are shared. (Use `variable_scope` to reuse the weights)
3. Then train the network using the loss function `seq2seq.sequence_loss`.

An example code is given [here](https://github.com/google/seq2seq/blob/master/seq2seq/models/basic_seq2seq.py) and [here](https://github.com/udacity/deep-learning/blob/master/seq2seq/sequence_to_sequence_implementation.ipynb).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. One thing is still unclear. During training do we really pass the decoder the "real" outputs as we have them from our dataset instead of feeding the previous output of the sequence (as in a real case scenario where nothing of the sequence could be determined)?

Comment: In other words do we train using real targets / decoder inputs and then test on unseen data without inputs to the decoder (except the first one that is mandatory from the architecture) OR do we let our model be trained and tested without providing any decoder inputs. The former one feels like cheating but it could result in good behavior I could not guess right now

Comment: Think this way: The decoder input always comes from previous output. So the decoder is always fed some input. But during training, the output is `fixed`  to the actual target and this has shown to improve performance. You can have a look at seq-2-seq tutorial from tensorflow: https://github.com/google/seq2seq/blob/master/seq2seq/models/basic_seq2seq.py

Comment: thanks @vijaym, about output_layer  in 1.1, if I'm not mistaken that will project the decoder hidden layers to the targets. How do you build a sequence loss based on output_layer? Doesn't dynamic_decode only return hidden states? sequence_loss requires the decoder logits, how do you get that?